# Accessing variable size typdef'd complex type in Cython

Tags: cython

I'm using cython to interface with an external library that uses complex numbers. Depending on how the library was configured, they could be either 64 bit or 128 bit complex numbers. For variable size ints, for example, I can do:

```
cdef extern from "my_header.h":
    ctypedef int HeaderIntType
```

which allows `HeaderIntType` to be either `int` or `long` depending on how it is typedef'd in the header files. But when I try

`ctypedef complex HeaderComplexType`

inside of my cdef extern, I get an error that complex external typedefs are not supported.

Is there a good way to achieve what I want, i.e. being flexible with my complex type depending on how the library was built?

---

Update:

My goal, in minimal form, is the following:

```
cdef extern from "my_header.h":
    int c_function(ComplexType* c)

def spam(np.ndarray[ComplexType,mode='c'] a not None):
    c_function(&a[0])
```

`c_function` is defined with the argument of type `ComplexType` in `my_header.h`, where I want to handle the case of `ComplexType` being typedef'd as a 64 bit or 128 bit complex. So I'm not sure fused types will handle this well. any tips? (When I try naively just using a fused type, gcc complains about an implicit declaration of the functions `__pyx_fuse_0c_function` and `__pyx_fuse_1c_function`, because it is trying to find both in my header file, and those obviously aren't there).

Answer (score 1):

Cython has [fused types](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html#selecting-specializations) exactly for this purpose:

```
ctypedef fused ComplexType:
    np.complex64_t
    np.complex128_t

def foo(ComplexType[:,::1] A):
    cdef np.ndarray[ComplexType,ndim=2] B
    print(42)
```

You can call it from python like

```
a=rand(3,3) + rand(3,3)*1j
foo(a)  # complex128 case
a=a.astype(np.complex64)
foo(a) # complex64 case
```

Comment: That seems to solve part of my problem. I'd like python code accessing my cython extension to be able to declare numpy arrays with the correct type, which I then access in C--I'm not sure fused types could be used for that. Can they somehow?

Comment: Yes, cython will generate the right functions for you. Depending on how you are interfacing with C, you can do quite a bit of this at cython level. See the edit

Comment: see update--I'm not sure fused types can go all the way for me.